# Making a track as a graphic progress bar in django and google-map

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

I appreciate if someone could tell me what is the best way to go. I would like to create a king of progress bar on a specific route on a google map or any other map. I need to put a picture of any car I want, and will be following a specific route.

For instance, I make a route from Los Angeles to San Francisco. I am going to get a route. And depending on how many kilometer I have, the car has to move. It is like a progress bar but following the specific bar. In the same way a GPS shows the car move.

Any ideas or sugestions. Thank you.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/ with google.maps.Marker use an icon of a car and google.maps.Polyline for the route.